# Avaya Orchestration unable to run the welcome TTS message

Tags: java, avaya

I am new to Avaya Orchestration. I created a simple flow but I wasn't able to execute it. The call flow detects no errors but when run the application on tomcat, i hear a tone and the call was hanged with the error as below.

```
Personal Voice Browser Version 7.2.1.5 Copyright (c) 2004-2018, Avaya
App Log: EVENT Id(2) Label() Msg(Error:  error.badfetch.http.500 ,  Error fetching document http://localhost:8080/Test2/Start?call_classification=live_voice&sagecfhport=36988&sagecfhhost=DESKTOP-V8KBQ1P&session___sessionid=sess7528920&session___vpconverseondata=)
Playing text "      Your application is having a problem.  The event ", Language (en-us), Gender (Female)
Playing text "error.badfetch.http.500", Language (en-us), Gender (Female)
Playing text " was caught      ", Language (en-us), Gender (Female)
Playing text "      with message ", Language (en-us), Gender (Female)
Playing text "Error fetching document http://localhost:8080/Test2/Start?call_classification=live_voice&sagecfhport=36988&sagecfhhost=DESKTOP-V8KBQ1P&session___sessionid=sess7528920&session___vpconverseondata=", Language (en-us), Gender (Female)
Playing text "      , Since no event handler was found, the application is exiting.         ", Language (en-us), Gender (Female)
End of Dialog
```

The server logs show the following error after execution:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ProtocolSocketFactory
```

I expect the welcome TTS message to run.

Comment: have you checked the servers error log to see why there's a 500?

Comment: The server logs show the following error: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ProtocolSocketFactory

Comment: I guess you are missing a library or using the wrong version